# What verb is appropriate to use for dream?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

What can I use instead of ... in the following sentence? I mean some verb that "make true" / "support"  my childhood dream!

Later on, in high school I was always thinking about choosing a field of study that not only increases my technological knowledge but also …. My childhood dream to be a business woman.

Comment: I would say "Fulfills".

Comment: "to fullfil" is better than "to realize" in this context, IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say:

I was always thinking about choosing a field of study that would enable me not only to increase my technological knowledge but also to **realize** my childhood dream of becoming a business woman

Comment: done :) (was the previous version wrong? or just unidiomatic?)

Comment: or **realise**, depending on which country you're from!

Comment: Actually it would need to be "help me (to) realize" or similar. The study cannot realize a dream, but the person studying can!

Comment: @nxx you're right. edited my answer. see if it's better now

Comment: @stackUnderflow about the realize/realise controversy, see here http://grammarist.com/spelling/realise-realize/

Comment: @MdMazzotti Perfect!